# *** buffer overflow detected ***

Tags: gcc

my program was compiled properly with "make" on Ubuntu 11.04, but when i run it, it give error.
is this a bug on Ubuntu? or this is difference in variable types between compilers?
pls help me

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: src/trilearn_player terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x50)[0x9cd0a0]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xe5f7a)[0x9cbf7a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__strcpy_chk+0x3f)[0x9cb30f]
src/trilearn_player[0x804dd24]
src/trilearn_player[0x808b2d5]
src/trilearn_player[0x80920cf]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x8fce37]
src/trilearn_player[0x804a421]
======= Memory map: ========
00139000-0015d000 r-xp 00000000 08:0b 6060       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
0015d000-0015e000 r--p 00023000 08:0b 6060       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
0015e000-0015f000 rw-p 00024000 08:0b 6060       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
001b4000-001b5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00488000-0049d000 r-xp 00000000 08:0b 6831       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
0049d000-0049e000 r--p 00015000 08:0b 6831       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
0049e000-0049f000 rw-p 00016000 08:0b 6831       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
0049f000-004a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00558000-00637000 r-xp 00000000 08:0b 134145     
00637000-0063b000 r--p 000de000 08:0b 134145     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
0063b000-0063c000 rw-p 000e2000 08:0b 134145     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
0063c000-00643000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0087b000-00885000 r-xp 00000000 08:0b 6826       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
00885000-00886000 r--p 00009000 08:0b 6826       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
00886000-00887000 rw-p 0000a000 08:0b 6826       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
008e6000-00a42000 r-xp 00000000 08:0b 5792       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
```

Comment: Show us the code. It is almost certainly not a bug in Ubuntu.

Comment: The stacktrace show you are using `strcpy` somewhere in your code, and it's in there the overflow happens. The reason is probably that the destination buffer you copy to is to small, so you copy outside of allocated memory.

Comment: When I first started learning to program I learnt quickly the value of humility in the face of the machine. It worked out better for me to assume that I was wrong, my program was wrong, the stuff I was doing was wrong, than to blame something else.

Comment: I suggest you build with debug information turned on (add `-g` to your `CFLAGS` in the makefile) and learn to use a debugger to find the location of the bug.

Comment: thanks to all
This is 2D_Soccer_simulator_team's program and i don't know where the error occurs.
I'm sure that source code is properly, because i had installed it on the Suse 10.

Comment: just because your code runs on a platform does not mean your code is bug free. The bug is still there, its just exposed in a certain circumstances.

Comment: SUSE 10 is quite old, and might not have had the stack-checking facilities that modern distributions has. Which is why it "worked" there. Post code! See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 6):

/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__strcpy_chk+0x3f)[0x9cb30f]

Looks like you copy too many chars to the destination.

Comment: im facing the same issue,You have pointed out the problem,but any idea what the fix is?